# Emptying a listbox programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to clear `listbox` everytime when `addImages` button is clicked which adds new items to it but I am facing problem in clearing it. Following is my code:

```
private void addImages_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    FileInfo Images;
    string[] filenames = null;
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filenames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);

        foreach (string image in filenames)
        {
            Images = new FileInfo(image);

            if(Images.Extension.ToLower() == ".png" || Images.Extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || Images.Extension.ToLower() == ".gif" || Images.Extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || Images.Extension.ToLower() == ".bmp" || Images.Extension.ToLower() == ".tif")
            {
                ImageList.Items.Add(new LoadImages(new BitmapImage(new Uri(image))));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried `ImageList.items.clear()`, `BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(ImageList)` but these removed items first time only when button is clicked next time onwards they don't clear the list. I want list to be cleared everytime when button is clicked.

Comment: This is WinForms, not WPF. Could you change your tag, please.

Comment: Just a quick note, you can do `if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` instead of storing it in a variable that you don't seem to use again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below should work properly. the only thing that might be problematic

```
private void addImages_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    ImageList.Items.Clear();
    RefreshList();

    FileInfo Images;
    string[] filenames = null;
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filenames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);

        foreach (string image in filenames)
        {
            Images = new FileInfo(image);

            if(new string[]{".png", ".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".tif"}.Contains(Images.Extension.ToLower()))
            {
                ImageList.Items.Add(new LoadImages(new BitmapImage(new Uri(image))));
            }
        }
    }

    RefreshList();
}

private void RefreshList()
{
    // Force visual refresh of control
    ImageList.Refresh();
}
```

*note i cleaned up the extension validation

Edit : I just noticed you talk about Bindings. well you problem is easy then. you cannot clear a list binded to a control. the control will keep original source. You can only UPDATE a binding source otherwise you need to manually update the binding.

Binding on collection is a like a climbing.

Control is the person
Ropes are the DataSource(collection)
Mountain is your model

If in your model you clear (cut) the source (all ropes)
the Control (person) still hold the source (ropes)

If you want the control (person) to have a new source (rope)
You need to add a new one so he can jump on it an remove old ones.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox.Items.Clear` should clear the list, if you need that to happen *every* time the button is clicked then you need it in your event handler i.e.

```
private void addImages_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Items.Clear();
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I have tried that already, it removes items first time only when button is clicked later on it deosn't.

Comment: @badrulmuneer see update, you had it tagged as `WPF` when I answered originally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
ImageList.Images.Clear();
listBox.Items.Clear();
```